# Why NaN's reduce return?

Tags: javascript, reduce

I commented out the `return sum`, on purpose, because it does not work as expected.
If I remove return sum, it returns the right average. But this is what I don't understand: when it enters the if in the last index position, this return shows NaN.
But why does it return NaN?

```
const mediaNumeros = numeros.reduce((sum, element, index, array) => {
    sum = sum + element;
    if (index == array.length - 1) {
        return Number((sum / array.length).toFixed(2));
    }
    // return sum;
}, 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us assume the value of numeros be [8, 90, 0, 7]

Let's see what's going on in each iteration:-

**On the first iteration:**
before calculating `sum`

- array: [8, 90, 0, 7]
- element: 8
- index: 0
- sum: 0

After calculating `sum`

- array: [8, 90, 0, 7]
- element: 8
- index: 0
- sum: 8

**If we don't return `sum` after first iteration:**

**On the second iteration:**
before calculating `sum`

- sum: `undefined`
- array: [8, 90, 0, 7]
- element: 90
- index: 1

**NOTE**: Array.prototype.reduce() accepts a function (i.e it is higher order function) **and not a loop**.

`sum` becomes undefined as we did not return the value of the previous function call . Js engine has no idea what is the value of `sum` as the previous function has finished and its execution context is deleted.

**After calculating `sum`**

- sum: `undefined` + 90 = `NaN`
- array: [8, 90, 0, 7]
- element: 90
- index: 1

**So the value of `sum` becomes NaN**

So it continues to caluculate the value of `sum` as NaN.